# Pyspark extract multivalued column to another table

Tags: python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a csv file with one of the columns named id and another one named genre, that can contain any number of them.

```
1,Action|Horror|Adventure
2,Action|Adventure
```

Is it possible to do something like select a row, and for each genre insert into another dataframe current id and genre.

```
1,Action
1,Horror
1,Adventure
2,Action
2,Adventure
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a udf to split the genre data and use explode function.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType,StringType
s = [('1','Action|Adventure'),('2','Comdey|Action')]
rdd = sc.parallelize(s)
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd,['id','Col'])
df.show()
 +---+----------------+
 | id|             Col|
 +---+----------------+
 |  1|Action|Adventure|
 |  2|   Comdey|Action|
 +---+----------------+

newcol = f.udf(lambda x : x.split('|'),ArrayType(StringType()))
df1 = df.withColumn('Genre',explode(newcol('col'))).drop('col')
df1.show()
+---+---------+
| id|    Genre|
+---+---------+
|  1|   Action|
|  1|Adventure|
|  2|   Comdey|
|  2|   Action|
+---+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Suresh solution, you can also use `flatMap` after splitting your string to achieve the same:

```
#Read csv from file (works in Spark 2.x and onwards 
df_csv = sqlContext.read.csv("genre.csv")

#Split the Genre (y) on the character |, but leave the id (x) as is
rdd_split= df_csv.rdd.map(lambda (x,y):(x,y.split('|')))

#Use a list comprehension to add the id column to each Genre(y)
rdd_explode = rdd_split.flatMap(lambda (x,y):[(x,k) for k in y])

#Convert the resulting RDD back to a dataframe
df_final = rdd_explode.toDF(['id','Genre'])
```

`df_final.show()` returns this as output:

```
+---+---------+
| id|    Genre|
+---+---------+
|  1|   Action|
|  1|   Horror|
|  1|Adventure|
|  2|   Action|
|  2|Adventure|
+---+---------+
```

Comment: could you please comment what  each line does exactly?